# How to assign cv_results_['params'] from GridSearchCV

Tags: python, pandas, scikit-learn

I want to build a dataframe with cv_results but GridSearchCV is giving a list back. Dont know how to assign mat to ind to make a dataframe.

Here an example

```
from sklearn.feature_selection import SelectKBest, f_classif
from sklearn import datasets

diabetes_X, diabetes_y = datasets.load_diabetes(return_X_y=True)

# Split the data into training/testing sets
X_train = diabetes_X[:-20]
X_test = diabetes_X[-20:]

# Split the targets into training/testing sets
y_train = diabetes_y[:-20]
y_test = diabetes_y[-20:]

pipeline = Pipeline([
                     ('kbest', SelectKBest(f_classif)),
                     ('regressor', KNeighborsRegressor())
                    ])

parameters = {'kbest__k':  list(range(1, X_train.shape[1]+1)),
              'regressor__n_neighbors': list(range(1,21))}

grid = GridSearchCV(pipeline, parameters)
grid.fit(X_train, y_train)


mat = grid.cv_results_['mean_test_score']
ind = grid.cv_results_['params']
```

Output of `params` look like this:
[image]

Comment: What do you mean with 'do not know how to add mat to ind to make a dataframe'? However, if you are looking for the best found parameters you have to call ```grid.best_params_```, instead of ```grid.cv_results_['params']```

Comment: yes, i understand. Maybe my english is too bad to explain what i want. I want to get a matrix with all params. So i can make a heatmap. At x and y i want for example the neighbors and k. at z i want the score.